# Java overwriting an existing output file

Tags: java, append, overwrite

My program is currently using

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("output", true);
```

A while loop creates the output file if it is not yet created and appends some data to this file for every iteration of the while loop using

```
 output.write(data).
```

This is fine and is what I want.

If I run the program again the file just doubles in size as it appends the exact information to the end of the file.  This is not what I want.  I would like to overwrite the file if I run the program again.

Comment: Set append to `false`, if you cannot do that then you can `File.deleteOnExit()`.

Answer (score 34):

[This documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) suggests that the parameter you're passing is the `append` parameter.

the signature looks like the following

```
FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
```

You should set that parameter to `false` since you don't want to append.

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("output", false);
```

Answer (score 17):

> I would like to overwrite the file if I run the program again.

Pass `false` as 2nd argument, to set *append* to false:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("output", false);
```

Check out the [constructor documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29):

> If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

Comment: This works.  I'm not sure why though.  I thought changing that to false would continually overwrite my loop data rather than the whole file which would be bad.  If you feel like explaining that would be awesome but no big deal.  But yes that worked, thank you.

Comment: You open a file in either append mode or write mode. After that whatever you write to the file, will be done accordingly. Mode is specified only while opening a file. If you want to append next time, you would need to close the file, and re-open it in append mode.

Comment: the default value there is `false`

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just delete the file if it's there, and then always create it and job done.